# 403 response while accessing Discord API through chrome extension environment

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, google-chrome-extension, discord

I'm trying to access the Discord [get-user](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/user#get-user) endpoint. My goal is to do it through an extension. The code in the extension goes as follows"

user.ts:

```
interface discordUser {
  id: string
  username: string
  discriminator: string
  avatar: string
  bot: boolean
  system: boolean
  mfa_enabled: boolean
  banner: string
  accent_color: string
  locale: string
  verified: boolean
  email: string
  flags: number
  premium_type: number
  public_flags: number
}

export async function getUserData(
  userID: string,
  botKey: string
): Promise<string> {
  const res = await fetch(`https://discord.com/api/v9/users/${userID}`, {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bot ${botKey}`,
    },
  })
  if (!res.ok) {
    throw new Error(`Something went wrong ${res.status}`)
  }
  const data: discordUser = await res.json()
  return data.username
}
```

However, when I try to run the following code in the chrome extension I'm making, I get a 403 response:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()
popup.js:79 Error: Something went wrong 403
    at popup.js:118
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (popup.js:104)
```

I've tried essentially the same thing, but in a node runtime, code goes as follows:

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch')

async function getUserData(userID, botKey) {
  const res = await fetch(`https://discord.com/api/v9/users/${userID}`, {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bot ${botKey}`,
    },
  })
  const data = await res.json()
  console.log(data)
}

getUserData(userID, botkey)
```

Surprisingly, if I run essentially same code in Node, it gives me a positive response, with the needed characteristics (all user info):

```
{
  id: '657988964107550739',
  username: "pepegan't",
  avatar: 'd2277fa1dac4b69115a0edf30b0fd53f',
  discriminator: '0409',
  public_flags: 128,
  banner: 'a0a2f731f1ca90b948449c1d2156d28f',
  banner_color: '#ee88ab',
  accent_color: 15632555
}
```

I'm not sure what's the issue here ...

Comment: If you are not sure about the issue, what's not working ? What is not going such as you want ?

Comment: @Elikill58 so, the typescript code outputs an error, but the same code in node doesn't. I need the typescript code to give me the response that node code gets me

Comment: what do you mean node runtime? do you mean running without typescript?

Comment: @wisnuaryadipa i just run it via my cmd, executing the file through "node app.js"